# jQuery only move one element

Tags: jquery

Here are the code:

```
....
<table>
<?php 
$count=1;
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) { 
?>
  <tr>
  <td>data 1</td><td>data 2</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="<?php $count; ?>"></td>
  </tr>
<?php 
  $count++; 
} 
</table>
<input type="button" id="del" value="delete">
?>
....
```

For my js file:

```
$("#del").click( function() {
  $("table input").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $product_key = $(this).attr('id'); 
      $checked_row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
      $.post("one.php", {product_id: $product_key}, function(){
          $checked_row.remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

If I ticked more than one checkbox, only one row is deleted each time I clicked delete button. Why?  I want to delete all the rows I ticked. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $product_key = $(this).attr('id'); 
var $checked_row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

you have to use `var` otherwise these variables has global scope.
so in your callback for `$.post`, `$checked_row` refer last one.

Answer (score 0):

Store all the checked_rows and do a single post ***after*** the `.each`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#del").click( function() {
    $("table input:checked").each(function(){
        var $product_key = $(this).attr('id'); 
        var $checked_row = $(this).closest('tr'); 
        $.post("one.php", {product_id: $product_key}, function(){
            $checked_row.remove();
        });
    });
});
```